# Sorting Data monthly after using groupBy in pandas

Tags: pandas, sorting

I am using the below code to first group my data so that I can get total Sales Quantity for a Material in a given Territory and in a given month.

```
Material_Wise = data.groupby(['Material','Territory Name','Month'])['Gross Sales Qty'].sum()
print(Material_Wise)


Material    Territory Name  Month
A           Region 1        Apr 2017     40000.0
                            Aug 2017     12000.0
                            Dec 2017     12000.0
                            Feb 2018     50000.0
                            Jan 2017     50000.0
                                           ... 
E           Region 2        Nov 2019      9000.0
                            Oct 2018      2000.0
                            Oct 2019     22900.0
                            Sept 2018    10000.0
                            Sept 2019    14200.0
```

Above is the output I am getting, Now I want to sort my data such that, I can get an output as shown below:

```
Material    Territory Name  Month
A           Region 1        Jan 2017     50000.0
                            Apr 2017     40000.0
                            Aug 2017     12000.0
                            Dec 2017     12000.0
                            Feb 2018     50000.0

                                           ... 
E           Region 2        Sept 2018    10000.0
                            Oct 2018      2000.0
                            Sept 2019    14200.0
                            Oct 2019     22900.0
                            Nov 2019      9000.0
```

Comment: u mind sharing the original df, before the groupby? a couple of rows will do

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Month` column is of string data typem, the default ordering behavior is to sort alphabetically. To sort it semantically, you need to convert it to *ordered categorical* type.

```
# Convert the months from strings to Timestamps (Apr 2017 -> 2017-01-01), drop the duplicates,
# sort them, and convert them back to strings again.
# The result is a series of semantically-ordered month names
month_names = pd.to_datetime(data['Month']).drop_duplicates().sort_values().dt.strftime('%b %Y')

# Create ordered category of month names
MonthNameDType = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(month_names, ordered=True)

# This will appear the same after the conversion. To check, you can use `data.dtypes` before
# and after
data['Month'] = data['Month'].astype(MonthNameDType)

# And groupby as usual
Material_Wise = data.groupby(['Material','Territory Name','Month'], observed=True)['Gross Sales Qty'].sum()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, it worked fine. There is just one issue, Month Sept is not being displayed, all other months are sorted as required other than that.